# Stand Alone usage of RHCL utility

Tags: robohelp

I have few queries regarding the usage of RHCL utility. The following are my queries:

a) Can this utility be run stand alone, i.e without installing the Robo-Help or it is always required to install the entire Robo-Help to run this command line utility

Example:

```
RHCL D:\sukanta\workings\projects\VSTS\RoboHelp\PCC_Contract\PCC_Contract.xpj -l "WebHelp" -o D:\sukanta\workings\projects\VSTS\RoboHelp\OutPutTest
```

b) Is there any licensing cost is involved, if we want to use RHCL only to build the output from the source

Answer (score 0):

RHCL is the command-line interface for robohelp classic.  It is installed with and depends on all the same things that the robohelp UI depends on.

If you try to run RHCL without a license, it will exit with an error "Your license is either invalid or expired."